# How to add Angular component content dynamically?

Tags: angular, angular7

I want to crate a nested layer.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'items-collection',
    template: '<ng-content></ng-content>'
})
export class ItemsComponent {
}
```

HTML usage is like this:

```
<items-collection>
    <item [name]="item-1"></item>
    <item [name]="item-2"></item>
    <item [name]="item-3"></item>
</items-collection>
```

But if I set a json source data of items-collection the data will append dynamically.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'items-collection',
    template: '<ng-content></ng-content>'
})
export class ItemsComponent {
    private jsondata:any[] = [
        {"name": "item-8"}, 
        {"name": "item-9"},
        {"name": "item-15"}
    ]
}

<items-collection source="jsondata">
    <item [name]="item-1"></item>
    <item [name]="item-2"></item>
    <item [name]="item-3"></item>
</items-collection>
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Why is *ngFor not useful in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine `<ng-content>` with a normal `*ngFor`:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'items-collection',
    template: `
      <ng-content></ng-content>
      <item *ngFor="let item of source" [name]="item.name"></item>
    `
})
export class ItemsComponent {
  @Input() source?: { name: string }[];
}
```

Make sure to use input binding

```
<items-collection [source]="jsondata">
    <item [name]="'item-1'"></item>
    <item [name]="'item-2'"></item>
    <item [name]="'item-3'"></item>
</items-collection>
```

Comment: @khush if he wants some default items in the list

Answer (score 1):

In ItemsComponent,

```
@Component({
    selector: 'items-collection',
    template: `<ng-container *ngFor=let data of jsonData">
                  <item [name]="data.name"></item>
              </ng-container>`
})  
export class ItemsComponent {
    @Input('source') jsonData: any[] = [];
}
```

And where you want to include item-collection,

In that component ts and html file include this code,

```
private jsondata:any[] = [
        {"name": "item-8"}, 
        {"name": "item-9"},
        {"name": "item-15"}
    ]


<items-collection [source]="jsondata">       
</items-collection>
```